# How to reload a div from a form inside itself?

Tags: php, ajax, forms, html, reload

I am working on a webpage where I have a main landing-page that has a div that loads different pages; I did this so the entire page doesn't reload but ajax just sends out a call to load a different page within that div. I already have calls from the main landing-page able to redirect the div; but I am unable to get calls from inside the div to redirect the div.

My question is on one of the pages that is loaded inside the div I have a form. I would like that form when submitted to do some php tasks and then depending on the result load a different page within the div; but what happens now is my whole page is refreshed.

I do not need an exact answer but just a general approach and minor code for a situation like:
If in this form someone enters 'yes' and hits enter the div will refresh to 'a.php' and if they enter 'no' the div will refresh to 'b.php'; and if they enter nothing the div will reload itself with the same form page.

Some relevent code would be...
landing-page (outside div):

```
//all the ajax that handles the reloading
<form>
<select id="ajaxmenu" size="1">
<option value="p1.php">Page 1</option>
<option value="p2.php">Page 2</option>
<option value="p3.php">Page 3</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onClick="ajaxcombo('ajaxmenu', 'contentarea')" value="Go" />
</form>
<div id="contentarea"></div>
```

form-page (inside div):
A basic php page with a form... I feel like I must have to somehow change the action and method; and possibly add javascript to this page but I'm not exactly sure what to do.

```
<form action='' method='POST'>
word:<input type='text' name='value'>
<input type='submit name='submit'>
```

Thank you very much for your time; and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also two general approached I thought of which may work but not 100% sure could be:
1)Have the form submit itself refreshing the div with a link that has values stored in the link; then do all the php work and then deciding to send out another refresh.
2)Have to form to a java function on click and handle all the data in java code; then do a div refresh.

In both these cases I run into a brick will with having the child page in the div send a refresh command to the parent page to refresh the div. Sorry if I sound dumb; I fair decently well with php; and am bad at java & ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution, a much easier one at that is using an iFrame. Ex:

```
    <iframe src="your_page.php" scrolling="no" frameBorder="0" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;height:100%;background-color:#ffffff;">
If you are seeing this your browser does not support iFrames.</iframe>
```

When you load a page within an iFrame your browser completely loads the other page executes/renders it and then imports the resulting html into your page; unlike a div which just imports the code and renders within the page after importing. This is very useful because if you have a page inside an iFrame and you click a link within that page it will just reload the iFrame with that new page. It would work just like any-other page; making it much easier because you will not need AJAX to swap between pages even when form data is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

When all else fails..... Build a bigger box. You already know how to submit the page with jquery and ajax. What i would do is create another hidden division is the same spot as this one. Submit the form with ajax and return the response into the other division, simply replacing the existing one.